# How do you calculate the height of the title bar in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to display one form relative to a Button on a control below it.

But Button.top is relative to the **titlebar** of the bottom form, and the top form will be relative to the screen.

So, to compensate for that I need to now how tall the titlebar is.

I've used Form.height-Form.ScalehHeight but ScaleHeight doesn't include the title bar **or** the border so Scaleheight is inflated slightly.

Anyone know how to calculate the height of *just* the title bar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subtract it back out:

```
(Form.height-Form.ScaleHeight) - (Form.Width-Form.ScaleWidth) / 2
```

Comment: Elegant!
FYI, There's a typo, fixed below.  (I don't have enough rep to edit)
(Form.height-Form.ScaleHeight) - (Form.Width-Form.ScaleWidth)

Comment: We use the same technique. There is still a typo. As written above, you are subtracting twice the border. Should be (Form.height-Form.ScaleHeight) - (Form.Width-Form.ScaleWidth)/2

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the `GetSystemMetrics` API call to get the height of the titlebar.

```
Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Const SM_CYCAPTION = 4

Property Get TitleBarHeight() as Long
    TitleBarHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION)
End Property
```

Note: This will return the height in pixels. If you need twips you will have to convert using a form's `ScaleY` method like so: `Me.ScaleY(TitleBarHeight(), vbPixels, vbTwips)`

Answer (score 3):

"Recursive's" answer above is not quite correct. It subtracts twice the border width - there is a border on the left and one on the right!

We get the best results with this:

```
(Form.Height-Form.ScaleHeight) - (Form.Width-Form.ScaleWidth)/2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
' For completeness:
Public Const SM_CYCAPTION = 4
Public Const SM_CYBORDER = 6
Public Const SM_CYFRAME = 33

' in Pixels
Property Get NonClinetHeight()
    FrameH = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME)     ' Total height, Top + Bottom
    CaptionH = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) 
    BorderH = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER)   ' Border around Client area
    NonClinetHeight = FrameH + CaptionH + (BorderH * 2)
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to make a Win32 API call to [GetSystemMetrics()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ClientToScreen()` windows API function to convert a point from client coordinates to screen coordinates:

```
Dim Position As Point

Position.x = 0
Position.y = 0
ClientToScreen Me.hWnd, Position
FormTop = Position.y
```

If you want to skip this and go direct to the button, you can use the button's position (in pixels):

```
Position.x = This.ScaleX(Button.Left, this.ScaleMode, vbPixels)
Position.Y = This.ScaleY(Button.Top, this.ScaleMode, vbPixels)
...
```

Or just get the buttons position using `GetWindowRect()`

```
Dim Position2 As Rect

GetClientRect Button.hWnd, Position2
Position.x = Position2.left
Position.y = Position2.top
...
```